# $\phi \mapsto f\circ \phi$ and $\phi \mapsto \phi\circ f$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider the function $f: E \to F.$ And let $G$ be the third set with at least two elements, we construct two new functions as follows:
$$f_*:\begin{cases}
E^G \to F^G \\ 
\phi \mapsto f\circ \phi
\end{cases}   
f^*:\begin{cases}
G^F \to G^E \\ 
\phi \mapsto \phi\circ f
\end{cases}
$$
The problem is to show that: $$f \text{ is injective} \iff f_* \text{ is injective} \iff f^* \text{ is surjective}\text{ } (*)$$
And: $$f \text{ is surjective} \iff f_* \text{ is surjective} \iff f^* \text{ is injective} \text{ } (**)$$
This seems like a plain "please do my homework for me" kind of situation but I genuinely spent hours thinking about this and all I was able to do is prove the (trivial) first equivelance in $(
*)$. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm proving the second equivalence from the first line, in the hope that this will get you moving. Let me know with a comment if you need more help.

Suppose $f$ is injective and $\psi \in G^E$. We wish to construct $\phi \in G^F$ such that $\psi = \phi \circ f$. Fix $y \in F$, and define:
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}\psi \circ f^{-1}(x) & \text{if }x \in \operatorname{Range} f \\ y \ & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
Note that $f^{-1}(x)$ is well-defined for $x \in \operatorname{Range} f$ due to injectivity. The choice of $y$ is arbitrary, since $\phi \circ f$ will only ever feed elements of $\operatorname{Range} f$ into $\phi$.

Suppose $f$ is not injective. Then $f(a) = f(b)$ for some $a \neq b$ in $E$. Therefore, $(\phi \circ f)(a) = (\phi \circ f)(b)$, for all $\phi \in G^F$, which is a limiting condition, as $|G| \ge 2$. In particular, let $c, d \in G$ be distinct, and consider the following $\psi \in G^E$:
$$\psi(x) = \begin{cases} c & \text{if }x = a \\ d \ & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$
For the reason stated above, there can be no $\phi \in G^F$ such that $\psi = f^*(\phi)$.

Comment: I don't understand the choice of $\psi$...

Comment: Do you not understand how it's defined, or why there is no $\phi$ such that $\psi = f^*(\phi)$?

Comment: I can see how it's defined but it seems arbitrary to me, let alone how it helped in the proof.

Comment: There is some arbitrary choices to be made, yes, but the way it helps is that $\psi(a) = c \neq d = \psi(b)$. If $\psi = \phi \circ f$, then we would have $\psi(a) = \phi(f(a)) = \phi(f(b)) = \psi(b)$, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: But I don't see how it's necessary to have $\psi=\phi \circ f$

Comment: It's not. What I'm saying is that it's impossible to have $\psi = \phi \circ f$, thus proving that there is no $\phi$ such that $f^*(\phi) = \psi$, i.e. $\psi \notin \operatorname{Range} f^*$, i.e. $f^*$ is not surjective. However, under **the assumption** (for the sake of contradiction) that $\psi = \phi \circ f$ for some $\phi$, we can obtain a contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry but to my mind it seems that would only prove that there is no function $\phi$ such that $\phi \circ f$ equals the $\psi$ you defined, not any $\psi \in G^E$

Comment: That's true, and that's OK. You don't have to show that **all** $\psi \in G^E$ are not in the range of $f^*$ (of course there will be **some** $\psi \in \operatorname{Range} f^*$, since the domain of $f^*$ is non-empty!). What's important is that there are **some** $\psi$ that are not in $\operatorname{Range} f^*$. That is, the range is **not all** of the codomain $G^E$.

Comment: As an analogy, think about proving $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2$ is not surjective. You pick a strictly negative number (e.g. $-1$) and argue that there is no real number $x$ such that $x \mapsto -1$.  The argument doesn't sink just because there *is* an $x$ such that $x \mapsto 1$!

Comment: I see now... thanks for your patience! Also, if you don't mind, I could use some hints on $(**)$ but that's not necessary, thank you anyway.

Comment: Well, to show $f$ is surjective implies $f_*$ is surjective, you want assume $\psi \in F^G$ to find $\phi \in E^G$ such that $\psi = f_*(\phi)$. You'd ideally like $\phi = f^{-1} \circ \psi$, but the problem is $f^{-1}$ is multivalued. However, if you set $\phi$ to be just one arbitrary element of $f^{-1} \circ \psi$ (you'll need axiom of choice for this; it can't be done constructively), then you'll be fine.